# ComboBox, Button & ICommand bindings (MVVM-ish)

Tags: wpf, binding, icommand

Given the following XAML...

```
<ComboBox x:Name="advisoriesComboBox"
  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Advisories}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedAdvisory}" />

<Button Command="{Binding Path=AddAdvisoryCommand}"
  CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=advisoriesComboBox, Path=SelectedItem}"
  CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=advisoriesComboBox}"
  Content="Add..." />
```

I am looking for a way to bind the ComboBox, Button and Command in such a way that when the value of the ComboBox changes, CanExecute is called on the Command. The net effect of what I want is to be able to enable and disable the Button based upon which item is selected in the list and I would prefer to do this using the ICommand interface.

I have done this in the past by using the "SelectedAdvisory" property on the VM and manually calling RaiseCanExecuteChanged on the command objects (I am using DelegateCommand instances from PRISM v4), but I feel sure that there is a better and cleaner way to do this using XAML only.

Thanks.

EDIT: Additionally, is there a simpler way to reference the ComboBox from the Button? I tried using RelativeSource PreviousData but could not get it to work, hence the usage `x:Name`.

Thanks again.

Comment: What you've done in the past looks pretty good to me. I'm not sure XAML is a better place for this stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have setup now is what I would do. If the command can execute or not is a business rule, which means it should be handled from the `ViewModel`, not the `View`.

The only difference is I make is to raise the `CanExecuteChanged()` in the `PropertyChange` event of your ViewModel, instead of the `set` method of `SelectedAdvisory`

```
void MyViewModel()
{
    this.PropertyChanged += MyViewModel_PropertyChanged;
}

void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch(e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "SelectedAdvisory":
            ((DelegateCommand)AddAdvisoryCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
            break;
    }
}
```

I prefer to keep logic out of my getters/setters if possible, and using the `PropertyChanged` event lets me see everything that happens when properties change in one location.

Of course, if you're using a `RelayCommand` instead of a `DelegateCommand` you don't need to manually raise the `CanExecuteChanged()` when properties change since it does it automatically.

You can also simplify your XAML a bit providing both share the same `DataContext`. The `Button` shouldn't need to reference the `ComboBox` at all.

```
<ComboBox
  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Advisories}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedAdvisory}" />

<Button Command="{Binding Path=AddAdvisoryCommand}"
  CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedAdvisory}"
  Content="Add..." />
```

Comment: INotifyPropertyChanged is how I handle it now, the only difference being that I require all command objects to requery CanExecute for all property changes rather than requerying selectively. Thanks.

Comment: I agree. If you want a "shortcut", then `RelayCommand` is a nice `ICommand` implementation. I prefer the `DelegateCommand` instead... The `RelayCommand` executes far too often because it ties into the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` event. This makes debugging annoying.

Answer (score 2):

i would do all in the viewmodel, seems to me the best when it comes to unit test

```
<ComboBox x:Name="advisoriesComboBox"
  DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Advisories}" 
  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedAdvisory}" />

<Button Command="{Binding Path=AddAdvisoryCommand}"
  Content="Add..." />
```

vm

```
private bool CanAddExecute()
{
   return this.SelectedAdvisory != null; 
}

private void AddExecute()
{
   if(!CanAddExecute())
      return;

   //do here what you want, your information for the selected item is in this.SelectedAdvisory 
}
```

code is handwritten, so there may be some errors.

Comment: This works, but I kind of like the idea of the command handler being passed the object to work on (as per Rachels's suggestion). Thanks.